# Присваивается класс только первому элементу из массива m1 через forEach

Tags: javascript

Присваивается класс только первому элементу из массива m1.
К остальным не присваивается

Пробовал даже обернуть в Array.from

```
let m12 = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-mounth="12"]')),
    m1 = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-mounth="1"]')),
    m6 = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-mounth="6"]'));

let b12 = document.querySelector('.period-12'),
    b1 = document.querySelector('.period-1'),
    b6 = document.querySelector('.period-6');

if(b12.classList.contains('filter--active')) {

    m1.forEach(function(elem1){
    elem1.classList.add('d-none').remove('d-block');
    });

    m6.forEach(function(elem6){
    elem6.classList.add('d-none').remove('d-block');
    });
};
```

Comment: `elem1.classList.add('d-none').remove('d-block');` зменить на это -> `['d-none', 'd-block'].map(cssClass => elem1.classList.toggle(cssClass));`, или remove второй строкой делать